# Match Contents Between Malformed Numbered List (1., 2., 3., etc), Regex

Tags: php, regex

Dealing with this crazy string that is a conversion from a PDF to text framework.

I'll post it at the end but it is probably easier to decipher here: https://regex101.com/r/DxXupz/1

I figured out how to match the contents between `1.` and `2.` using this regex:

```
1\.(.*?)2\.
```

But as you can see the `$string` I'm dealing with has all sorts of numerics and decimals and the like, and goes all the way up to `11.`

Is there a regex solution to capture all the numbered lists in one `preg_match_all` function query, ie (example with regex above for `1.` to `2.`):

```
preg_match_all('/1\.(.*?)2\./s', $string, $matches);
```

To bring back the contents from `1.` to `2.`, `2.` to `3.`, and so forth?

> 

```
$string = "1. CZ243 96V DC   

20
0pcs  


11.35U
SD            220
.
00
USD


2
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .

2.

CV243 96V DC  

10
0pcs  


11.35USD            1135
.00
USD  


4
”

,74mm/s


25lbs

3
. CV243 96V DC   

150pcs         12.20
U
SD           1830.00
USD


6
”

,74mm/s   


25lbs .

4. CV243 96V DC  

100
pcs        13.50
1USD            1350.00
USD


8
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .

5
. CV243 96V DC 

50
pcs    

15.00USD     

750.00
USD


10
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .

6. CV243 96V DC   

200pcs 

15.00USD    

3000.00
USD


12
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .

7
. CV243 96V DC  


50pcs 


16.00USD           800.00
USD


14
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .

8. CV243 96V DC   

75pcs         16.50
USD



1237.50
USD


16
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .

9. CV243 96V DC               
5
0pcs 


18.46USD           
923.00
USD


18
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .


10.CV243 96V DC               
50pcs 


18.46USD 

923.00
USD


20
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .


11. 
CV243 96V DC               
5
0pcs 


20.77USD           1038.50
USD


24
”

,74mm/s 


25lbs .


";
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Yeah. The string is way screwed up with the PDF to conversion. So my original regex `1\.(.*?)2\.` works fine to get the contents from `1.` <---> `2.`... to get the contents from `2.` <---> `3.` I would need to do `2\.(.*?)3\n\.` (note the `\n`) because the text decided to do a line break before the period and after the `3`... it's complicated I know :/ Not sure if I should do this one by one or if there is a universal Regex (or something else) I can do to retrieve the numbered lists contents all in one search.... Perhaps it is easier to understand if to know that all numbered lists start with

Comment: a # (`1` - `11`) and then the words `CV243 96V DC`.. (i know my head is turning too..)

Comment: Your string has the first piece (after `1.`) starting with `CZ243`, not `CV243`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should give you the results you want:

```
\d+\s*\.\s*(CV243 96V DC.*?)(?=\d+\s*\.\s*CV243 96V DC|$)
```

It looks for some digits, followed optionally by whitespace, a period, some possible whitespace and the string `CV243 96V DC`. It then grabs all the characters up to the next occurrence of the starting pattern or the end of the string (asserted using a positive lookahead so the characters are not captured in that match). In PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\s*\.\s*(CV243 96V DC.*?)(?=\d+\s*\.\s*CV243 96V DC|$)/s', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The output is somewhat messy so I won't repeat it all here but you can see this in operation in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/jqTYi). Here are the first two values:

```
[0] => CV243 96V DC 20 0pcs 11.35U SD 220 . 00 USD 2 ” ,74mm/s 25lbs . 
[1] => CV243 96V DC 10 0pcs 11.35USD 1135 .00 USD 4 ” ,74mm/s 25lbs
```

**Note**

I've assumed your data is supposed to start with `1. CV243`, not `1. CZ243`. If it supposed to start with `1. CZ243` and you still want to capture that, change the `CV243` in the regex to `C[VZ]243`.

Comment: Ahh.. you're a hero! I was seriously losing my mind trying to figure this out haha. Works like a dream. Will make note of the syntax for future scenarios.. huge help.